# Jquery Bind Events Don't Respond

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, unobtrusive-javascript

I'm trying to basically increment and decrement a vote count when a button is pressed (I've dumbed down the situation to exploit my error); I bind two different buttons with click events;however, I fail to get any response out of them (tested with Firebug).

Jquery Code:

```
//This Code is located within Application.js (Rails)
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.buttonUp').bind('click', function() {
        var voting_element = $(this).closest('.current_vote');
        voting_element.text( Number(voting_element.text()) + 1 );
    });
    $('.buttonDown').bind('click', function() {
        var voting_element = $(this).closest('.current_vote');
        voting_element.text( Number(voting_element.text()) - 1 );
    });
});
```

Each button with class buttonUp or buttonDown is located within a form containing the single submit button.

I am doing this in Rails 3.1.3 and using the following versions of the Jquery Library:

Jquery-Rails => 1.0.12
Jquery => 1.6.1
JqueryUI => 1.8.12
JqueryUJS => The one that comes with Jquery-Rails above.

Live doesn't work either, I wasn't expecting it would since I wait for the document to load before I bind the methods to the buttons.

Here is a snippet of the HTML in question.

```
<tr>
    <td>pop</td>
    <td>pop</td>
    <td><a href="/posts/12">Show</a></td>
    <td><a href="/posts/12/edit">Edit</a></td>
    <td><a href="/posts/12" data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow">Destroy</a></td>
    <td><p>
      <b>votes: </b>
    </p>
      <p class="current_vote">
        1
      </p>
      <form action="/posts/increaseVote?id=12" class="button_to" data-remote="true" data-type="json" method="post"><div><input class="buttonUp" type="submit" value="increaseVote" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="TxEGwONzSD+tnJ19iHMdGjuCBJMFoNJdECEspDtZxxY=" /></div></form>
      <form action="/posts/decreaseVote?id=12" class="button_to" data-remote="true" data-type="json" method="post"><div><input class="buttonDown" type="submit" value="decreaseVote" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="TxEGwONzSD+tnJ19iHMdGjuCBJMFoNJdECEspDtZxxY=" /></div></form>
  </tr>
```

Comment: Can you please also post the HTML?

Comment: Why do you have two `ready` events in the same js file?

Comment: I don't know, I originally had one, but I have been switching so many things to try to get any functionality out of this. Feel free to switch it to cleaner format.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Also, it likely won't fix your issue, but you don't need to do `.closest('#current_vote')` since ids are unique (just do `$('#current_vote')`) and your `voting_element` variable is a jQuery object, but then you do `$(voting_element)`, which is unnecessary.

Comment: Will edit, never had a chance to actually execute the code inside ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get pointed in the right direction, have a look at this [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/srBRp/2/).

Here's the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function vote(el, amt) {
        var $counter = $(el).siblings('.counter');
        $counter.text(parseInt($counter.text(), 10) + amt);
    }

    $('.voteUp').bind('click', function() {
        vote(this, 1);
    });

    $('.voteDown').bind('click', function() {
        vote(this, -1);
    });

});​
```

Comment: So there is actually a reason why I am using a binding method, I will eventually change the 'click' event to be that of a successful ajax call (since the button sends JSON to the server via ajax to update the db of the new vote).